# Show/Hide div element using drop down menu in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am new in Angular. I want to show/hide the file div using drop down (Select) menu.If I choose "custom", it will show File element. But I choose "none", it will hide as well as remove the file (if any) element. I am unable to show the hidden file element. Please provide some feedback?

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="credentials">Credentials</label><br />
  <select name="select_file" class="form-control" required ng-model="myVar">
    <option value="">Choose a option</option>
    <option value="false">none</option>
    <option value="true">custom</option>
  </select>
  <div *ngIf="myVar">
    <input
      type="file"
      class="form-control"
      id="credentials"
      accept=".json"
      [(ngModel)]="userdata.credentials"
      (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)"
      name="credentials"
    />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <div class="form-group">
  <label for="credentials">Credentials</label><br/>
  <select name="select_file" class="form-control" required [(ngModel)]="myVar">
    <option value="">Choose a option</option>
    <option value="false">none</option>
    <option value="true">custom</option>
</select>
<div *ngIf="myVar === true">
    <input 
    type="file" 
    class="form-control" 
    id="credentials" 
    accept=".json"
    [(ngModel)]="userdata.credentials"
    (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)"
    name="credentials" 
    >
  </div>
```

You need to use **ngModel** .
In Ts file, just define **myVar** variable.Please try this code.

Comment: Your answer is correct. But value is replaced by [ngValue]  as it supports any type, including boolean.

Comment: @YatishBathla You are right, value is always a string. But in our case, I guess it will not cause any issue. Because in div we have if condition of **myVar === true** .So it will not allow empty string also. Only value true will get allowed

Comment: I have tried with value but then file div is not visible when i clicked on custom option.

Comment: Oh okay, sorry my mistake. I forgot to do a quote. Try this  *ngIf=" myVar === 'true' " .

Answer (score 1):

First of all it's not a Angular JS, it's looks like Angular 2+.
About your problem:

```
[value]="..." only supports string values
[ngValue]="..." supports any type, including boolean
```

e.g.

```
<h1>My Application</h1>
<select [(ngModel)]="myVar">
  <option [ngValue]="''">Choose a option</option>
  <option [ngValue]="false">none</option>
  <option [ngValue]="true">custom</option>
</select>
```

Also try to use [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) instead of ngModel